# Writing blog using playframework

Tags: wordpress, playframework, blogs

I have a system build using playframework 2.0. I want to have blog to run on with the system. Is there a way i can do that?, something like plugins available for use or can I use word press to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a blog engine for Play Framework: https://github.com/jroper/erqx.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a new installation of wordpress, If you want to have 1 database for your playframework and wordpress then on the installation page it will ask you for a database, just enter the same database details that you have for playframework. Wordpress uses mysql so make sure you are using mysql for your playframework.

Its always better to have a different database but if you need to have some kind of integration between the two then it would be much better if you have them both on the same database.

Now in the sitename you can add something like

```
http://www.example.com/blog
```

OR

```
http://www.blog.example.com
```

Which ever you prefer. Once installed login to your wordpress admin area, install a blog theme and start creating your new blog posts. And in your main playframework website, create a new menu item and add this link to it.

I dont know of any plugins for playframework, but there is a plugin in wordpress that makes it work as an api, https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/. And then there is an addon to this plugin called https://github.com/mattberg/wp-json-api-auth.

You can install these 2 plugins in your wordpress and then from your playframework's registeration code make simple REST calls to the api. This will will be used to automatically register/login user's in wordpress. So when they login to playframework they will automatically get logged in to wordpress as well.